# Property 'from' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavigateProps' - react-router-dom v6

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I migrated from react-router-dom 5 to version 6 and the `Navigate` you see below used to be `Redirect`. The problem is that `from` from `from={from}` (the first one) errors saying

> Type '{ key: string; from: string; to: any; }' is not assignable to
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavigateProps'.   Property 'from' does not
> exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavigateProps'.

I don't know if it has to be replaced with something else from v6 of react-router-dom but any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    const redirects = routeAliases(routes).map(({ from, to }) => {
    return <Navigate key={`${from}-${to}`} from={from} to={{ ...location, pathname: to }} />;
  });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 to fully replicate the v5's `Redirect` component with `from` prop you must render the `Navigate` component in a `Route` component.

```
<Route path={fromPath} element={<Navigate to={toPath} replace />} />
```

Applied to your code snippet:

```
const redirects = routeAliases(routes).map(({ from, to }) => (
  <Route
    key={`${from}-${to}`}
    path={from}
    element={<Navigate to={{ ...location, pathname: to }} replace />}
  />
));
```